# Integrating over multiplication of a point by its probability

Tags: probability

suppose we have a normal distribution $ N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then 
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$

$$
CDF(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(t)d_t = \phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})
$$

Now assume that there is a point $S_1 \leq \mu$, I wonder how we calculate

$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{S_1} (S_1-x)f_X(x)d_x
$$

Answer (score 0):

I solve this as follow:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{S_1} (S_1-x)f_X(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{S_1} (S_1-x+\mu-\mu)f_X(x)dx \\ \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{S_1} (S_1-\mu)f_X(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{S_1} -(x-\mu)f_X(x)dx 
$$

for the first term we can write:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{S_1} (S_1-\mu)f_X(x)dx =(S_1-\mu)*\int_{-\infty}^{S_1} f_X(x)dx = (S_1-\mu)*\Phi(\frac{S_1-\mu}{\sigma})
$$

and for the second term we can write:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{S_1} -(x-\mu)f_X(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{S_1} -(x-\mu)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{S_1} -(x-\mu)e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \\ = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right]_{-\infty}^{S_1}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(S_1-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$

Can anyone verify that this calculation is correct?